# With react and material-ui, can I have some paper expand to full width outside a Container?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

If I have:

```
   <Container maxWidth='lg'>
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={6} >
        <Image src="/img/undraw_programming_2svr.png" color='transparent' aspectRatio={1041 / 554} />
      </Grid>
<SomeElement />
    </Container>
```

How can I have `SomeElement` expand to full width?

Comment: Is `someElement` in Grid container or not? What do you mean by full width? Container element width or screen width?

Comment: have you tried set container's position as relative and someElement position as absolute?

Comment: When you say full width, what do you mean? Also what styles do you have on Container and is SomeElement within the Grid or not. Your question doesn't have enough information currently

Comment: Your markup is wrong, additional to the above questions. the first `Grid` is wrongly closed/opened. Is `SomeElement` a sibling to the `Grid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, A few things that were already mentioned, Your grid tagging is wrong and I understand that it's a mistake and probably not essential to your question.

The answer to your question is no, the point of the container is to stop SomeElement from expanding. A simple fix, however, would be to stop the container, render SomeElement, and then start a new container.

```
<Container>
...
</Container>

<SomeElement />

<Container>
...
```